# Difference between '&' and '==' while using Qt mouse functions?

Tags: c++, qt

I was reading the documentation of Qt example of ["scribble"](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/widgets-scribble.html). There I stumbled across the following piece of code:

```
 void ScribbleArea::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
     if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && scribbling)
         drawLineTo(event->pos());
 }

 void ScribbleArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
     if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && scribbling) {
         drawLineTo(event->pos());
         scribbling = false;
     }
 }
```

One question arised in my mind on whether there's actually any difference between `event->button() == Qt::LeftButton` and `(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)`. Could you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: I am not  that familiar with QT but maybe its that (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) will also check right button...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *bitwise AND operator (&)* compares each bit of the first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand.

The `operator==` compare both operands to see if the values are equal.

That is, for you:

```
event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton
```

Will be true if the `LeftButton` bit is set and **other bits may also be set.**

```
event->button() == Qt::LeftButton
```

Will be true if only the `LeftButton` bit is set and **other bits should not be set.**

---

An example on how it works :

```
enum
{
    BUTTON_LEFT = 1 << 0,
    BUTTON_RIGHT= 1 << 1,
    BUTTON_MID  = 1 << 2
};

int a = 0;
a |= BUTTON_LEFT;
a |= BUTTON_RIGHT;
a |= BUTTON_MID;

if ( a & BUTTON_RIGHT )
    std::cout << "The button right is pressed." << std::endl;

if ( a == BUTTON_RIGHT )
    std::cout << "There is only the button right." << std::endl;
```

The output of this will be: `The button right is pressed.`. http://ideone.com/BunrTs

Answer (score 1):

```
event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton
```

This is true if the `LeftButton` bit is set; other bits may also be set.

```
event->button() == Qt::LeftButton
```

This is true if *only* the `LeftButton` bit is set; other bits may *not* be set.

Comment: So, the codes `((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && scribbling)` and `(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && scribbling)`  will yield different results? I could see that the second one would produce `true` if only the left button is pressed, but the first one will yield `true` despite the right button is pressed?

Comment: @the_naive: That's right. `&` is testing a single bit, while `==` is testing all bits.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me.

Assuming the mouse buttons are represented as unique bit "flags", the first tests if the left mouse button is pressed, while filtering out any other buttons that might have been pressed at the same time.

The second, however, *requires* that only the left button has been released. So if you do a double-press to start scribbling, then release both buttons at the same time, it should fail to detect the release.

**UPDATE**:

[This random Qt reference](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qt.html#MouseButton-enum) seems to support the assumption, at least:

```
Qt::LeftButton    0x00000001 The left button is pressed, or an event refers to the left button. (The left button may be the right button on left-handed mice.)
Qt::RightButton   0x00000002 The right button.
Qt::MidButton     0x00000004 The middle button.
```

Also, as pointed out by brilliant commentor [@svk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151753/svk), the two use different ways to access the mouse button flags, so it should be fine.

The fact that release events don't ever report multiple buttons is one of those things you learn after working with Qt for a while, something I haven't done. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Not sure this is a bug. Notice that there are two different methods: `button()` and `buttons()`. For a mouse release event, there's only one button being released.

Comment: @svk Thanks! That's weird, your comment is the best answer.

Comment: As I found out, `button()` or `buttons()` is always 0 on release. Don't know if this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in case of `mouseMoveEvent` method `event->buttons()` is used (it has "**s**" at the end) and it returns state of multiple buttons. So if many buttons are down many flags will be set.

In contradiction in case of `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mousePressEvent` method `event->button()` is used (no "**s**" at the end), and this return which button invoke this event this means that only ONE flag is set and it is possible to use equal operator.

When you note that check [already excepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18528134/1387438) from Mike Seymour.

Off-topic: in Qt flags have also [`testFlag` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qflags.html#testFlag).